# Right justify text using SharpDX/Direct2D

Tags: c#, drawing, directx, direct2d, sharpdx

I have some code to draw some text:

```
 var textFormat = new SharpDX.DirectWrite.TextFormat(fontFactory, "Arial", SharpDX.DirectWrite.FontWeight.Bold, 
        SharpDX.DirectWrite.FontStyle.Normal, SharpDX.DirectWrite.FontStretch.Condensed, 16.0f);
    renderTarget.DrawText("AC", textFormat, textRect, textBrush, DrawTextOptions.NoSnap);
```

The text is drawn starting at the top-left of the target rectangle. Is there any way to right-justify the text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fourth entry for the google search "right justify text sharpdx direct2d" shows me the [documentation](http://sharpdx.org/documentation/api/t-sharpdx-directwrite-textformat) of the `TextFormat` class, which has the property `TextAlignment`. Sometimes a little search is faster then to use Stackoverflow ;)